# Unable to generate an application key

Tags: spotify, libspotify, spotify-app

When I browse to [Libspotify's application keys page](https://devaccount.spotify.com/my-account/keys/), I'm asked to login. I do (with a premium account), and I'm tossed through a loop back to that first screen asking me to login again.

I need an application key (spotify_appkey.key) to get started, but it seems impossible. Anybody have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI Spotify has fixed the issue. Should now be able to generate keys as expected.